# 'Performance' tab of the task manager is frozen

Tags: windows-10, freeze, task-manager, windows-10-v1909

The 'Performance' tab of the task manager is frozen in Windows 10 (V1909). I can select options to change the views of the graph but this screen is particularly frozen. It happened all of a sudden and the other tabs are working just fine. Surely there is a solution to this.

[Frozen 'Performance' tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU481.png)

Comment: Start with basic repair:  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run: dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth . Follow with SFC /SCANNOW . When both are complete, restart and test. If DISM fails, run a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have already started others but isn't is too much to repair-installing the OS for just a task-manager frozen issue?

Comment: If DISM and SFC do not fix things, then Repair Install is the next step. Start with Keep Everything. It is easy to do but takes an hour or two watching paint dry while it completes

Comment: In Task Manager:click View  .   Check that Update speed is set to Normal or High   - Restart your PC after?

Comment: After the dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth, then SFC /SCANNOW & restart, it's finally fixed. Thanks bunch @John & Natsu Kage

Comment: If I post my comment as an answer, will you accept it?

Comment: Sure, I can think about it if I get an upvote on my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with basic repair: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run: dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth . Follow with SFC /SCANNOW . When both are complete, restart and test.  This fixes most issues.

Answer (score 38):

I just had exactly the same problem, and found that somehow my task manager had been paused.

Check the "view" menu, and under update speed change it from paused to normal (or high).

I don't know how this ever got changed, and can't help to wonder if it was after an update.

Comment: To think of it now, I also got the problem after an update.

Comment: Thanks! That's what caused my problem. No idea why it is paused though.

Comment: This was also the solution for me!

Comment: Wow! it just solved my problem. I can't believe the solution was so simple, I suffered from it for years. Thank you so much!

Comment: This should be an accepted answer!

Comment: it is an accepted answer! thanks.