# Task Manager pauses itself

Tags: windows, windows-10, task-manager

My Task Manager randomly pauses itself. That's very annoying. It seems to be random. I keep it open in the background and after half a day it's paused. Sometimes it works for days. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Try running DISM / SFC .   dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth followed by SFC /SCANNOW and restart, test

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question (thus the comment) but Task manager was never intended to be run 24/7.  The task manager itself uses a chunk of resources.  Perhaps there is a lighter option to know whatever it is that you need to know.

Comment: Why would you keep it open for so long? There are way better monitoring options.

Comment: What are you trying to solve or accomplish leaving Task Manager open?

Comment: I do a lot of development and CPU and HDD activity is a pretty good proxy of any problems. It's useful to see few minutes of history, which I'd why i keep it open. Also TM sometimes starts paused!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Performance' tab of the task manager is frozen](https://superuser.com/questions/1521553/performance-tab-of-the-task-manager-is-frozen)

Comment: Not really :( I know it's paused. I'm reluctant to make it's registry read-only (it will surely randomly break one update or another). NO other solution proposed,